# Sagemaker training job failed - having issues executing user script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am very new to AWS Sagemaker and am trying to deploy my SKLearn script to an endpoint so that I can call it from within an Android app. I am following the code [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_randomforest/Sklearn_on_SageMaker_end2end.ipynb), and so far, getting each block to work with my script has worked. The block that is giving me issues is

```
sklearn_estimator.latest_training_job.wait(logs="None")
artifact = sm_boto3.describe_training_job(
    TrainingJobName=sklearn_estimator.latest_training_job.name
)["ModelArtifacts"]["S3ModelArtifacts"]

print("Model artifact persisted at " + artifact)
```

Specifically, the first line. When I run this block, I get this error:

```
UnexpectedStatusException                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-65920860bce1> in <module>
----> 1 sklearn_estimator.latest_training_job.wait(logs="None")
      2 artifact = sm_boto3.describe_training_job(
      3     TrainingJobName=sklearn_estimator.latest_training_job.name
      4 )["ModelArtifacts"]["S3ModelArtifacts"]
      5 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py in wait(self, logs)
   1994             self.sagemaker_session.logs_for_job(self.job_name, wait=True, log_type=logs)
   1995         else:
-> 1996             self.sagemaker_session.wait_for_job(self.job_name)
   1997 
   1998     def describe(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in wait_for_job(self, job, poll)
   3217             lambda last_desc: _train_done(self.sagemaker_client, job, last_desc), None, poll
   3218         )
-> 3219         self._check_job_status(job, desc, "TrainingJobStatus")
   3220         return desc
   3221 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in _check_job_status(self, job, desc, status_key_name)
   3381                 message=message,
   3382                 allowed_statuses=["Completed", "Stopped"],
-> 3383                 actual_status=status,
   3384             )
   3385 

UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job rf-scikit-2022-08-05-22-32-08-239: Failed. Reason: AlgorithmError: framework error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_trainer.py", line 84, in train
    entrypoint()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/training.py", line 39, in main
    train(environment.Environment())
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/training.py", line 35, in train
    runner_type=runner.ProcessRunnerType)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_training/entry_point.py", line 100, in run
    wait, capture_error
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_training/process.py", line 291, in run
    cwd=environment.code_dir,
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_training/process.py", line 208, in check_error
    info=extra_info,
sagemaker_training.errors.ExecuteUserScriptError: ExecuteUserScriptError:
ExitCode 1
ErrorMessage ""
Command "/miniconda3/bin/python SageMaker_Script.py"

ExecuteUse
```

SageMaker_Script.py is the name of my script. The relevant code in my script is:

```
if __name__ =='__main__':

print('extracting arguments')
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

# hyperparameters sent by the client are passed as command-line arguments to the script.
parser.add_argument('--model-dir', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_MODEL_DIR'])



# Data, model, and output directories
parser.add_argument("--model-dir", type=str, default=os.environ.get("SM_MODEL_DIR"))
parser.add_argument("--train", type=str, default=os.environ.get("SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN"))
parser.add_argument("--test", type=str, default=os.environ.get("SM_CHANNEL_TEST"))
parser.add_argument("--train-file", type=str, default="jumpstrain.csv")
parser.add_argument("--test-file", type=str, default="jumpstest.csv")

args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

print('reading data')
train_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(args.train, args.train_file))
test_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(args.test, args.test_file))

print('building training and testing datasets')
X_train = train_df[columns]
X_test = test_df[columns]
y_train = train_df[['Under-rotated']]
y_test = test_df[['Under-rotated']]

print('training model')
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

print('validating model')
pred_values = model.predict(X_test[columns])
print('f1-score:')
f1score = f1_score(y_test, pred_values)
print(f1score)

# persist model
path = os.path.join(args.model_dir, 'model.joblib')
joblib.dump(model, path)
print('model persisted at ' + path)
print(args.min_samples_leaf)
```

I am at a loss for what the issue is because, like I said, I am very new to AWS in general, and the error that it gives me is not super informative. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an error in your training script, to get started I would recommend you follow this step to step guide to create your training script and job for an SKlearn Model - https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/sklearn/using_sklearn.html#train-a-model-with-scikit-learn